# Why does the square root with a number with a variable exponent stay in the numerator and not go to the denominator?

Tags: calculus

For example $({\sqrt 5^x})$ derivative is $({\frac 12}{\sqrt 5^x}log(5))$

The chain rule is used, but it appears we never subtract one from the power of the square root like we usually do with the chain rule.

Why is this the case when we have a variable exponent within the square root?

Comment: This confuses the rules for power and exponential functions: $\frac{d}{dx} (x^a) = a x^{a - 1}$ but $\frac{d}{dx} (a^x) = a^x \log a$.

Comment: You subtract one and you get $\frac 1 2 * \frac 1 {\sqrt{5^x}} * 5^x * \log (5)$.  But $\frac 1 {\sqrt{5^x}}*5^x = \sqrt{5^x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the square root here.

Lets say we have a function like this:$$y=x^n$$$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=nx^{n-1}$$which is the rule you are familiar with.

However, if we have a function like this:$$y=a^{f(x)}$$$$\therefore\log(y)=\log(a^{f(x)})=f(x)\log(a)$$$$\therefore \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)\log(a)$$$$\therefore\frac{dy}{dx}=yf'(x)\log(a)=a^{f(x)}f'(x)\log(a)$$This is known as the power rule.

---

In your case we have $y=\sqrt{5^x}=5^{\frac{x}{2}}$ giving us $a=5$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, thus:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=5^{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{1}{2}\log(5)=\frac{1}{2}5^{\frac{x}{2}}\log(5)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5^x}\log(5)$$

Comment: Gah! So simple, but so easily confused. Thank you, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

We *do* subtract 1.  $\frac {d\sqrt{f(x)}}{dx} = \frac 1 {2\sqrt{f(x)}}*f'(x)$.

But in *this* case $f(x) = 5^x$ so $f'(x) = 5^x \log(5)$ and $\frac 1 {2\sqrt{5^x}}*5^x*\log(5) = \frac 1 2 * \sqrt{5^x}*\log(5)$.